# jQuery ajax call not working after having added form validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a jQuery ajax call which worked fine, until I added form validation. Now the validation works, but the ajax call doesn't, although I haven't touched it and the parameters sent seem ok.

jQuery code is:

```
$j('#leapYearBtn').click(function()
{
    $j('td#calcResMsg').html('');
    $j('#leapYearForm').validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element){
        error.appendTo(element.parent('td').next('td'));
    }
    });
    if($j('#leapYearForm').validate().element("#leap_year") == true)
    {
        var fctSelect = 2;
        var year = $j("#leap_year").attr("value");
        alert(fctSelect);
        $j.ajax({
            url: "ajax/clcDates.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {fctSelect: 2, yr: year},
            success: function(output){
            $j('td#calcResMsg').text(output);
        }});
    }       
});
```

HTML form:

```
<form id="leapYearForm">        
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td>Enter year</td>
           <td>
               <input class="required positiveNumber" type="text" name="leap_year" 
               id="leap_year" value="" />
           </td>
           <td class="validatorErrMsg"></td>
           <td id="calcResMsg" class="calc_resMsg">/td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td>
              <button id="leapYearBtn">Check</button>
           </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

When adding the validation, I have changed neither the php function nor the ajax call, yet it does not work any more. Can someone please help me to find out why ?

My suspicion is that it has something to do with the fact that I had to wrap the table in a form, which might affect the behavior somehow and result in the ajax call not even being made.

Thanks a lot

Comment: what is the value of `$j('#leapYearForm').validate().element("#leap_year")` ?  Probably not `true`.  I'd investigate from that angle, to start. (You might want to post a fiddle if you want others to assist the investigation.)

Comment: @jimmym715 actually it is, I checked it with alert. Would be happy to post a fiddle, however as I cannot put the ajax/php part don't know whether it would be of great help.